# React testing library stopPropagation

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I'm using the react testing library. My component on onKeyDown does validation + stopPropagation and changes do not go through in onChange. How to test this - can I make some kind of event pipeline (such as onChange being called after onKeyDown) so as not to do fireEvent.keyDown and then fireEvent.change and even do custom logic for stopPropagation.